# if is_singular array not working as expected

Tags: array, single

I'm using the following if statements within header.php to load custom tracking codes.

```
<?php if ( is_singular( array( 'custom-post-type', 'post-name' ) ) ) : ?>
     // Specific tracking code here
<?php endif ?>

<?php if ( is_singular( array( 'custom-post-type', 'another-post' ) ) ) : ?>
    // Specific tracking code here
<?php endif ?>
```

When I go to each post, both tracking codes are showing up. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It's not clear if you want to target specific posts (with  some slugs) or specific post types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an incorrect check here. [`is_singular()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) returns true when a post is from the specified post type or post types or the default post types when none is specified. You cannot target specific single posts with `is_singular()`

You have to use [`is_single`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) to target a specific post

```
if ( is_single( 'post-a' ) {
    // Do something for post-a
} elseif ( is_single( 'post-b' ) {
    // Do something for post-b
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have over complicated your parameter for "is_singular", or is "custom-post-type" an actual CPT of yours?

Try:

```
if ( is_singular( 'custom-post-type' ) ) {
  // Foo
} else if ( is_singular( 'another-custom-post-type' ) ) {
  // Bar
}
```